# Boolean Evaluation in Apex?

Tags: apex

Does anybody know if there is a way to evaluate a string containing boolean-logic at runtime? My logic, can only contain three operators and parenthesis (AND, OR, NOT). I can even make the string look like this: `true && false && (true || !true)`

I don't have the bandwidth to build a full-on parser... Any ideas?

PS: I saw some answers that pointed to the use of an API but I don't have access to use the Toolkit API in the environment this will get deployed.

Comment: Almost, those are all the operands that are allowed in this case.. plus `!`.

Comment: Yup, those are the ones.

Comment: @SebastianKessel What's the use case? Visualforce, Trigger, or Async code?

Comment: Visualforce, right now. Eventually Apex inside of a batch.

Comment: I'm willing to listen to any partial solutions, @AdrianLarson

Comment: Some old code on this that perhaps could be simplified for this requirement [Evaluate expressions/conditions in apex code ? (which are stored in string/text)](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20796/evaluate-expressions-conditions-in-apex-code-which-are-stored-in-string-text#20808).

Comment: Thanks Keith, it's a bit of overkill but should cover most of what I need. Make this an answer and I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Could you get away with the Dynamic Visualforce Component trick that @sfdcfox wrote about here? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47395/is-there-an-api-method-to-execute-or-evaluate-visualforce-or-workflow-functions

Comment: Nope... :( One half of the use case will run without a VF context.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got a fairly simple one working. It might not perform as well as a more sophisticated option, but it is easy to understand.

**Logic**

```
public class BooleanExpression
{
    static Boolean orJoin(String x, String y) { return evaluate(x) || evaluate(y); }
    static Boolean andJoin(String x, String y) { return evaluate(x) && evaluate(y); }
    static Boolean isSimpleExpression(String x) { return x == 'true' || x == 'false'; }
    static String simplify(String x)
    {
        x = x.trim();
        while (x.contains('('))
        {
            String sub = x.substringAfterLast('(').substringBefore(')');
            x = x.replace('(' + sub + ')', String.valueOf(evaluate(sub)));
        }
        return x;
    }
    static Boolean evaluate(String x)
    {
        x = simplify(x);
        if (!isSimpleExpression(x))
        {
            if (x.contains('&&')) return andJoin(x.split('&&', 2));
            if (x.contains('||')) return orJoin(x.split('||', 2));
            if (x.startsWith('!')) return !evaluate(x.substring(1));
        }
        return Boolean.valueOf(x);
    }
}
```

**Tests**

I know you can just use `assert(evaluate(expression))`, but that feels kind of dirty here.

```
@IsTest
class BooleanExpressionTests
{
    static testMethod void testExpressions()
    {
        system.assertEquals(true, evaluate('true'));
        system.assertEquals(false, evaluate('!true'));
        system.assertEquals(true, evaluate('!false'));
        system.assertEquals(false, evaluate('false'));
        system.assertEquals(false, evaluate('true && !true'));
        system.assertEquals(true, evaluate('false || !false'));
        system.assertEquals(true,
            evaluate('false || (false || (!true || (false || true)))'));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, it won't do 100% but it gets me far enough down the rabbit hole to complete it myself. Thanks!

Comment: For the record, I could recursively call your function with everything between `(` and `)`. I think that should work.

Comment: Recursion deepness is my biggest worry, but in my use-cases it won't be a problem. I'll need to think on this a bit, but I think I can make it work.

Comment: Wow. I JUST finished testing my solution, almost identical to yours. Here it is... check out the `simplify` method. https://gist.github.com/sebastiankessel/838773f98b33d9d24eeb

Comment: @SebastianKessel I thought that approach was at risk to replacing other matching substrings, but on second thought... I tightened up my presentation a bit.

Comment: I think that we have to evaluate parentheses from outside to inside (because of our recursiveness). So you want to take the first opening and last closing parenth, and evaluate that (with recursion, of course)

Comment: But, on second thought, either way works (inside out works too)

Comment: It's throwing CPU time exceeded exception when I evaluate this expression: '(true && true) || (true && (false || false || false))'

Comment: Please post a new question if you would like to ask something.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I am not asking anything .. just used this solution and it was working as expected but it's throwing exception "too many cpu time" for long expression. So I thought to share so that we can improve or find out any workaround if we have such long expressions. I went ahead and I developed a solution which is really very fast. Still I am testing use cases. Here is the link of source code; please suggest any improvement if I can do: https://gist.github.com/ayub-ansari/d689fe390e0f7350ce6600a09335981f

Answer (score 10):

One more way may be using [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) for evaluation of expressions without recursion and for linear time. My solution is just simplified version of [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20796/evaluate-expressions-conditions-in-apex-code-which-are-stored-in-string-text).

Example of implementation some comments:

```
public class RPN {
    //map with priorities    
    public static Map<String,Integer> OperatorsPriorities = new Map<String,Integer>{
         '*' =>  2, // AND binary
         '+' =>  1,// OR binary
         '(' => -1, //
         ')' => -2,
         '-' => 3  //NOT - unary
    };

    public static Boolean evaluateString(String param){
        String rpn_string  = buildRPN(param);
        return evalRPN(rpn_string);
    }

    public static string buildRPN(String param){
        param = param.replace('true','t').replace('false','f').replace(' ','')
            .replace('&&','*').replace('||','+').replace('!','-');
        //to make input string smaller, do some nice replacements
        List<String> stack = new List<String>();//represent stack
        String result = '';//Reverse Polish Notation string
        Integer counter = 0;//current character position
        while(counter < param.length()){//go through input string
            String p = param.substring(counter,counter+1);//get current character
            if (p == 't' || p == 'f'){//if that is a value
                result += p;//add to RPN
            }else{
                if (OperatorsPriorities.get(p) == -1){//if that is open bracket
                    stack.add(p);//add to stack
                }else if(OperatorsPriorities.get(p) == -2){//if that is closed bracked
                    while(stack.get(stack.size() -1) != '('){//pop stack until open bracket
                        result += stack.remove(stack.size() - 1);
                    }
                    stack.remove(stack.size() - 1);//remove bracket from stack
                }else {//if that is operator
                    while (   stack.size() > 0 
                           && OperatorsPriorities.get(p) <= OperatorsPriorities.get(stack.get(stack.size() - 1))){
                        result += stack.remove(stack.size() - 1);//pop from stack to RPN until operator with lower priority meet
                    }
                    stack.add(p);
                }
            }
            counter++;
        }
        while(stack.size()> 0){//pop stack to RPN result string
            result += stack.remove(stack.size() - 1);
        }
        return result;
    }


    public static string opposite(string param){
        return (param == 't')? 'f': 't';
    }

    public static boolean evalRPN(string prn){
        List<String> elements = prn.split('');
        Integer position = 0;
        while(elements.size() > 1){//evaluate rpn string unless 1 value left
            String element = elements.get(position);//get current position
            if (element == 't' || element == 'f'){//if that is value - go forward
                position++;
            }else{
                if (element == '-'){//unary operator - replace previous value and remove it
                    elements.set(position-1,opposite(elements.get(position-1)));
                    elements.remove(position);
                    position--;
                }else if (element == '*'){//binary operator - replace prev prev value and remove prev and current 
                    String par1 = elements.get(position - 2);
                    String par2 = elements.get(position - 1);
                    String res = (par1 == 'f' || par2 == 'f')? 'f' : 't';
                    elements.set(position-2,res);
                    elements.remove(position);
                    elements.remove(position-1);
                    position -= 2;
                }else if (element == '+'){//another binary operator
                    String par1 = elements.get(position - 2);
                    String par2 = elements.get(position - 1);
                    String res = (par1 == 't' || par2 == 't')? 't' : 'f';
                    elements.set(position-2,res);
                    elements.remove(position);
                    elements.remove(position-1);
                    position -= 2;
                }
            }
        }
        return  (elements.get(0) == 't')?true:false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but RPN Won't help me, I have a routine that writes this string and i can't change it. Besides, humans will read it and RPN is not as easy to understand.

Comment: Certainly harder for me to wrap my head around. Still, interesting approach. +1

Comment: Human doesn't need to read that (except in errors case). This consists of 2 modules, first one build rpn, second evaluate it. And, in case of understanding this simple version, it would be easier to build more complex one in future

Comment: +1 for RPN - along with its friend, the HP-45 calculator - without which I couldn't have done all my engineering problem sets as rapidly.

Comment: @kurunve, in my use case, I absolutely need a human to read it. Thanks, but this is not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A couple years back I converted an open source java boolean expression evaluator into Apex. The company I was working for at the time has given permission for me to release it to the public, so hopefully this will be helpful to someone.

https://github.com/mattsmall/apex-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this as one more solution of this requirement. Here I am just trying to get advantage of **Boolean calculation and replaceAll method of string class**. As a result, it becomes **very fast in execution** and we can use it in trigger as well.

Example:

String expression = 'false and (false or (true and (false or true)))';

//Run this one and check the CPU time and compare with other solution...apparently it would be faster
BooleanExpression.evaluateExpression(expression);

```
public class BooleanExpressionCalculation{

public static boolean evaluateExpression(String expression){
    system.debug(expression.containsIgnoreCase('false')+'__'+expression.containsIgnoreCase('true'));
    if(expression.containsIgnoreCase('false') == false){ return true;}
    if(expression.containsIgnoreCase('true') == false){ return false;}
    expression = runeval(expression);
    if(expression == 'true') return true;
    return false;
}

public static string runeval(String expression){
    if(expression.contains('true and true')||expression.contains('true and false')||expression.contains('false and true')||expression.contains('false and false')){
        expression = BooleanExpressionCalculation.replaceANDLogic(expression);
    }
    if(expression.contains('true or true')||expression.contains('true or false')||expression.contains('false or true')||expression.contains('false or false')){
        expression = BooleanExpressionCalculation.replaceORLogic(expression);
    }
    system.debug(expression+'___');   
    if(expression.contains('(true)')){     
        expression = replaceleftBrackets(expression);
    }
    if(expression.contains('(false)')){
        expression = replaceRightBrackets(expression);
    }
    system.debug(expression+'___');
    if(expression.contains('(')|| expression.contains(')') || expression.contains('or')|| expression.contains('and')){
        expression = runeval(expression);
    }
    system.debug(expression+'___final');
    return expression;
}

public static string replaceleftBrackets(string expression){
    expression = expression.replaceAll('\\(true\\)', 'true');
    if(expression.contains('(true)')){
        expression = replaceRightBrackets(expression);
    }
    return expression;
}
public static string replaceRightBrackets(string expression){
    expression = expression.replaceAll('\\(false\\)', 'false');
    if(expression.contains('(false)')){
        expression = replaceRightBrackets(expression);
    }
    return expression;
}

public static string replaceANDLogic(String exp){
    exp = exp.replaceAll('true and true', 'true');
    exp = exp.replaceAll('false and true', 'false');
    exp = exp.replaceAll('true and false', 'false');
    exp = exp.replaceAll('false and false', 'false');
    if(exp.contains('true and true')||exp.contains('true and false')||exp.contains('false and true')||exp.contains('false and false')){
        exp = replaceANDLogic(exp);
    }        
    return exp;
}
public static string replaceORLogic(String exp){
    exp = exp.replaceAll('true or true', 'true');
    exp = exp.replaceAll('false or true', 'true');
    exp = exp.replaceAll('true or false', 'true');
    exp = exp.replaceAll('false or false', 'false');
    if(exp.contains('true or true')||exp.contains('true or false')||exp.contains('false or true')||exp.contains('false or false')){
        system.debug('ayub___');
        exp = replaceORLogic(exp);
    }
    return exp;
}}
```

Source Code Link: https://gist.github.com/ayub-ansari/d689fe390e0f7350ce6600a09335981f